# Why can't I delete a layer in my private docker registry(v2)?

Tags: docker-registry

I have just installed the docker-registry in stand-alone mode successfully and I can use the following command

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:5000/v2/
```

to get the proper result.

However, when I use

```
curl -X DELETE http://localhost:5000/v2/<name>/blobs/<digest>
```

to delete a layer, it fails, I get:

```
{"errors":[{"code":"UNSUPPORTED","message":"The operation is unsupported."}]}
```

I use the default configuration from the docker hub. And I studied the official configuration but failed to resolve it.

How can I make it out?

Comment: Looks like similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29802202/docker-registry-2-0-how-to-delete-unused-images . Also,This issue was discussed here https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/422 .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to add the parameter delete: enabled: true in /etc/docker/registry/config.yml

make it look like that :

```
 version: 0.1
 log:
    fields:
        service: registry
 storage:
    cache:
        layerinfo: inmemory
    filesystem:
        rootdirectory: /var/lib/registry
    delete:
        enabled: true
 http:
    addr: :5000
```

take a look [here](https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/master/docs/configuration.md#delete) for more details

Or by adding an environment var to the container on boot :

```
-e REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED=true
```

Answer (score 16):

Either use:

```
REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED=true
```

or define:

```
REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED: "yes"
```

in docker-compose.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a full day with this

In case you have already added `delete: enabled`

```
storage:
  delete: 
    enabled: true
```

and/or `REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED=true`

And still does not work, ensure that you have not created your docker registry as a ***pull-through cache***. i.e, ensure that you don't have a `proxy` field

```
proxy:
  remoteurl: https://registry-1.docker.io
```

in your `config.yml`