# How to recover deleted docker image tags in private docker registry before garbage collection?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

Need to recover some deleted images from a private Docker registry, any suggestion? The layers should be still in place, garbage collection hasn't been run yet, is there a way to reverse the delete process?

[How to delete images from a private docker registry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25436742/how-to-delete-images-from-a-private-docker-registry)

[Docker Registry 2.0 - how to delete unused images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29802202/docker-registry-2-0-how-to-delete-unused-images/48950176#48950176)

Comment: Which storage back-end has been used and how did you start registry?